# MySQL service is stopped again and again in AWS server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

MySQL service is stopped in AWS server and not starting again and its give me error

MySQL Daemon failed to start.

Comment: Please remember to always include configuration that you are using. There are many possible reasons for such behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Just try restarting your EC2 instance.

Comment: I tried all methods from reboot to mysql log but no luck with it and I don't want to loose my database